# Sorting music into folders by metadata

Tags: software-recommendation, music, filemanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort music by metadata](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7225/sort-music-by-metadata)

I thought this would be easier to find but I have tried a number of programs and none seem to be able to do this the way I want.

Basically I want to be able to sort a mass of `.mp3s` into a specific folder on an external drive, separated and named by metadata. I used **foobar2000** on Windows to do this and it was perfect for my needs, the closest I've come on Ubuntu was **Picard** but, I can't get it to work with music not in the **Musicbrainz DB**, as I listen to a lot of mixtapes and live cuts so that isn't very helpful.

I want something with an output like "`External HDD/artist/album/(tracknumber)title`"
 (for example :"**External HDD/Nas/Illmatic/(01)The Genesis**").

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: [Reorder Files inside Folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47155/reorder-files-inside-folder) and [How to organize music files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85077/how-to-organize-music-files)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7225/sort-music-by-metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these:

1. [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard)
2. [Beets](http://beets.radbox.org/)

Also check this similar question:

[Sort music by metadata](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7225/sort-music-by-metadata)

Comment: Thank you, through a lot of trial and error I got Beets to do a reasonably good job of it, I'm sure with more practice it'll be perfect! Thanks again. 

P.S. I did try that thread already, it was what led me too Picard, it wasn't quite what I needed though. I didn't want to reopen an old question, sorry if I went about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an application which does just you want. Check it out [here](https://github.com/th0th/harmony). Foobar2000 was the application I was originally inspired by.

Comment: Hey that does look very useful, honestly though I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, and I couldn't figure out how to install it. I will check it out later as my knowledge improves.

Comment: It's a command line application, so requires a just a tiny bit command line experience.

Comment: Setup didn't work as advertised.  Option --prefix not recognised...